# cTransform.TransformFinalBlock always returns empty string?

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I have a simple encrypt/decrypt routine that works like a charm in Windows forms applications but always seems to return an empty string in asp.net application.

The code for encrypt and decrypt look like this:

```
   /// <summary>
/// Encrypt a string using dual encryption method. Return a encrypted cipher Text
/// </summary>
/// <param name="toEncrypt">string to be encrypted</param>
/// <param name="useHashing">use hashing? send to for extra secirity</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)
{
    byte[] keyArray;
    byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

    System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();
    // Get the key from config file
    string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", typeof(String));
    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(key);
    if(useHashing)
    {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        hashmd5.Clear();
    }
    else
        keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
    {
        Key = keyArray,
        Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
    };

    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
    tdes.Clear();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
}

/// <summary>
/// DeCrypt a string using dual encryption method. Return a DeCrypted clear string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cipherString">encrypted string</param>
/// <param name="useHashing">Did you use hashing to encrypt this data? pass true is yes</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Decrypt(string cipherString, bool useHashing)
{
    byte[] keyArray;
    byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString);

    System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();
    //Get your key from config file to open the lock!
    string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", typeof(String));

    if(useHashing)
    {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        hashmd5.Clear();
    }
    else
        keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
    {
        Key = keyArray,
        Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
    };

    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

    tdes.Clear();
    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
}
```

I have stepped the Decrypt code and everything seems fine until I get to the line:

```
byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
```

The toEncryptArray contains 8 bytes worth of values but when it's transformed into the resultArray it always ends up as an array of zero bytes?

I have the following usings at the top of my class:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
```

In my Web.config I have this line in the appSettings section:

```
<add key="SecurityKey" value="SomeRandomTextToMakeAKey" />
```

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Graham Sivill

Comment: ECB is insecure for most purposes, 2-key (128 bit) 3DES is considered insecure by now. MD5 is not a password generation function, passwords should not be used directly as keys. There are a scary number of things wrong with the above code from a security perspective and the algorithms used are thoroughly outdated. Funny enough, otherwise it does exactly what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have simply encrypted zero bytes. This gets expanded by the padding mode (PKCS#7) to eight bytes, as PKCS#7 *always* pads. Otherwise it would not be able to distinguish a decrypted plaintext that ends with `01` with a 7 byte plaintext and a padding byte.

So if you set the padding to no padding (`PaddingMode.None`) during decryption then you would probably get back 8 (padding) bytes valued `08`. Note that you would need to view this as hex as those bytes represent Backspace in ASCII.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what I should do to my code? Can you explain where the error is? I tried changing the padding mode to none and sure enough it returns 8 backspace characters \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b as the result.

Comment: Your encryption and decryption code works, although it is insecure. You need to ask yourself why your encryption code gets called with an empty string (or a string that encodes to an empty byte array anyway).

Comment: Maarten,
Actually I have discovered it does work. This is not used in any external facing

Comment: You have discovered what exactly? That encryption / decryption works, as in my answer & comment?

Comment: Maarten,
Actually I have discovered it does work. This is not used in any external facing
systems it's just really to obfuscate some passwords in the database the code is completely internal and never makes any internet access. I found that the input I thought I was supplying with the password (CipherString parameter) was actually faulty and was passing an empty string to the routine so what I was getting was an encrypted empty string.

Comment: Great, mystery solved I guess :) Note that ECB is still rather dangerous. Say that there is a 9 character password that ends with the letter X, then a user could simply try to encrypt a password that also ends with X, get the encrypted password, and compare the last blocks. If they are identical then the user guessed right.